# How to speed up the construction of a large matrix

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

As a part of a physics problem that I'm working on, I need to construct a rather large matrix. The matrix is a real symmetric $2^{m}\times 2^{m}$ matrix for some integer $m$, which we would like to make as large as possible, though of course calculations become increasingly impractical for large $m$. My code for constructing the matrix is the following:

```
transfermatrixmag = IdentityMatrix[2^m];

For[k = 1, k <= 2^m, k++, 
 For[j = 1, j <= 2^m, j++, 
   Part[Part[transfermatrixmag, j], k] = 
     Product[
       Exp[
         (Part[Part[Tuples[{-1, 1}, m], j], n] * 
            Part[Part[Tuples[{-1, 1}, m], k], n] + 
          1/2 Part[Part[Tuples[{-1, 1}, m], j], n] *
            Part[Part[Tuples[{-1, 1}, m], j], n + 1 - m*KroneckerDelta[n, m]] + 
          1/2 Part[Part[Tuples[{-1, 1}, m], k], n] *
            Part[Part[Tuples[{-1, 1}, m], k], n + 1 - m*KroneckerDelta[n, m]])], 
       {n, 1, m}]]]
```

This is obviously very inefficient, as it does not, for example, take advantage of the symmetry of the matrix (which I have called transfermatrixmag here). But it seems to me that the more fundamental limitation is the fact that one must do a computation for each entry of the matrix, making the construction of the matrix painfully slow. For example with $m=10$ the code takes about 1035 seconds, whereas performing multiplications with the resulting matrix or diagonalizing it takes on the order of 1 second. I'm sure it's possible to make significant optimizations to this, but I'm not really sure where to start. Can anyone offer some advice?

Comment: It would be useful to give some more information. For instance, do you have general formulas for the matrix elements?

Comment: Still not very efficient: `transfermatrix[m_Integer?Positive] := With[{tup = Tuples[{-1, 1}, m]}, Exp[Outer[Dot, tup, tup, 1] + Outer[Plus, #, #]/2 &[MapThread[Dot, {tup, RotateLeft /@ tup}]]]]`

Comment: If you can use numerical values instead of symbolic, it cuts the time in half.

Comment: @J.M.'s function can also be compiled, which gains an order of magnitude in speed. `transfermatrixNC = Compile[{{m, _Integer}}, With[{tup = Table[IntegerDigits[i, 2, m], {i, 0, 2^m - 1}]*2. - 1.}, Exp[Outer[Dot, tup, tup, 1] + .5*Outer[Plus, #, #] &[MapThread[Dot, tup, RotateLeft /@ tup}]]]], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]`

Answer (score 3):

J.M. commented with this much faster code:

```
transfermatrix[m_Integer?Positive] := With[{tup = Tuples[{-1, 1}, m]}, 
 Exp[Outer[Dot, tup, tup, 1] + Outer[Plus, #, #]/2 &[
  MapThread[Dot, {tup, RotateLeft /@ tup}]]]]
```

shrx provided a compiled version:

```
transfermatrixNC = Compile[{{m, _Integer}}, 
 With[{tup = Table[IntegerDigits[i, 2, m], {i, 0, 2^m - 1}]*2. - 1.}, 
  Exp[Outer[Dot, tup, tup, 1] + .5*Outer[Plus, #, #] &[
   MapThread[Dot, {tup, RotateLeft /@ tup}]]]], 
    CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

If machine precision is sufficient this is faster still:

```
transfermatrix[m_Integer] := With[{t = Transpose@N@Tuples[{-1, 1}, m]},
  Exp[Transpose[t].t + (Outer[Plus, #, #] &[Total[t RotateLeft[t/2]]])]]
```